# Installing Denkovi relay manager DRMv2.8

Tags: software-installation

I am new to the Raspberry Pi. I have been using Denkovi relays and their relay manager on Windows. There is a download for the Raspberry Pi, which I have downloaded and unzipped.

The problem is I can not manage to run the software. I know how the Pi terminal works, but don't know what to put in it to run the software.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you managed to get the program to produce any output (including an error)?

Comment: As is, your question is incredibly vague, and only a psychic could answer it. We need more information to go on. Where does this software come from? What is it written in? Did you check their webpage for instructions or prerequisite software?

Comment: Typically its ./scriptname

Comment: The software comes from the following:http://denkovi.com/drm-software#DRMIGFL.